# Apache Camel how to get the input xml payload size?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

Is there a way we can get the input payload size in exchange body.I would like to Gzip the content if the content size is more than 50 MB.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly roundabout, but I use camels [cache streaming](http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html). After setting it up, then just check if the body has been converted to a StreamCache. (A stream that allows multiple reads. Primarily useful if dealing with very large files). I have to deal with 10gb+ files, so this is a nice way to not burn out the jvm with outoffmemory, but also not worry about losing the payload by reading it.

The blueprint (not sure what jboss equivelent is) would like

```
<!-- define a bean of type StreamCachingStrategy which CamelContext will automaticly use -->
<bean id="streamStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultStreamCachingStrategy">
    <property name="spoolDirectory" value="${java.io.tmpdir}/camelcache/#uuid#/"/>
    <property name="spoolThreshold" value="52428800"/>
    <property name="spoolUsedHeapMemoryThreshold" value="70"/>
    <property name="anySpoolRules" value="true"/>
</bean>

<camelContext streamCache="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
```

You can create a [Predicate](http://camel.apache.org/predicate.html) bean to do the actual test, and use that in the camel route to affect flow control.

If you aren't worried about memory, you could be crazy, and in your predicate, take the payload as a stream, read all the bytes into memory as a byte[], and then test the size of the byte[] (Or count the bytes as you read them from the stream). Just depending on your payload source, you might not be able to reset the stream if you don't cache it first.

Comment: Hi Tezra,Thanks for your reply,but this answer my question.I would like to process in camel route in a different way if size is more than 50 mb. I am not facing oom issue in fuse, but there is limitations in downstream system.

Comment: @Ravi You can create a [Predicate](http://camel.apache.org/predicate.html) bean to do the actual test, and use that in the camel route to affect flow control. (Again, that's just how I'm doing it to keep it simple and robust). If you aren't worried about memory, you could be crazy, and in your predicate, take the payload as a stream, read all the bytes into memory as a byte[], and then test the size of the byte[]. Just depending on your payload source, you might not be able to reset the stream if you don't cache it first.

Comment: @vikingsteve I'm moving arbitrary files around based on their file type/contents. Most are actually a reasonable size, but every once in awhile, I get something big like a long, high quality video. So it's nice to not have to worry about the size of a payload as long as the server has the disk space for it. =P

Comment: Nice to know the camel framework is reliable under heavy loads.